# Importing csv file into mysql: Incorrect decimal value: '"0.5'

Tags: mysql

Can someone point me what I am doing wrong:
csv file:

```
weight,student,price
0.5,4,2.3
```

command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'prices.csv'
            INTO TABLE prices
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
            IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Error:

```
Incorrect decimal value: '"0.5' for column 'weight' at row 1
```

Comment: Please show us the table structure for `prices`.

Comment: Most likely your locale/collation uses `.` as the thousand separator and `,` as the decimal separator. `LOAD DATA` loads individual values correctly but the server can't convert these values to correct decimals. Try changing your connection's collation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a enclosing (or escaping) character in your file (I don't know your real file). Try to specify `ENCLOSED BY`

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'prices.csv'
INTO TABLE prices
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

If that doesn't work, try it with `ESCAPED BY` too.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'prices.csv'
INTO TABLE prices
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: Or the locale uses `,` as the decimal separator and `.` as the thousand separator (eg France, Germany, Greece)

Comment: This looks promising.  He shouldn't be getting that error if the data posted really looks like that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the real data is different from what he posted as there wouldn't be an error at all for the posted data @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos shouldn't it then be another error message?

Comment: the second query you provided, succeded! only for the first column 0.5 i got 0 (csv file has many rows) and all succeded except first one, but that's not problem i can insert it manualy

Comment: @Nikanor - still strange, usually all should succeed. Maybe check your file for inconsistancies..

Comment: i think 0 is making a problem in 0.5 - i dont know why, but thanks